# How to save ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

How to save an ArrayBuffer in json file? I use electron-config for this, but in config.json I found "{}". I try convert ([code](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String)) ArrayBuffer to string, but then I can't convert string to ArrayBuffer.

```
put: function(key, value) {
    //value = { prop1: <ArrayBuffer>, prop2: <ArrayBuffer> }
    if (key === undefined || value === undefined || key === null || value === null)
        return;
    var prop1Str,prop2Str;
    prop1Str = this.ab2str(value.prop1);
    prop2Str = this.ab2str(value.prop2);
    var chValue = {prop1:prop1Str, prop2:prop2Str};
    config.set(key,chValue);
    console.log(value.prop1 === this.str2ab(config.get(key).prop1)); //===> FALSE
},
ab2str: function(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
},
str2ab: function(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to store binary data in JSON? Are you sending an HTTP request to a server? If so, you'd be better off with something that is binary-friendly, such as multipart/form-data instead of JSON.

Comment: @mscdex Not necessarily in JSON format. I just want to save ArrayBuffer on PC.

Comment: You mean save it to a file on the local computer's disk or do you mean save it in the *browser*, like via LocalStorage (which does not support binary data natively btw)?

Comment: @mscdex I mean save it on the local computer's disk (Electron app).

Answer (score 5):

For saving to disk, you should be able to use the normal node APIs for writing something to disk. For example:

```
require('fs').writeFileSync('/path/to/saved/file', Buffer.from(myArrayBuffer));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no ArrayBuffers in the JSON format (only strings, numbers, booleans, `null`, objects and arrays) so if you want to save an ArrayBuffer in JSON then you'll have to represent it in one of those types (probably a string or an array of numbers).

Then when you read the JSON you will have to convert it back into an ArrayBuffer, reversing the transformation that you did before.

Comment: I just want to save ArrayBuffer in local DB or in file. I can't find a local database, do not store data in a JSON.

Comment: I know what I should convert an ArrayBuffer to a string, but I can't convert string to  ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

### Working Snippet Node 14.xx+

**Create a output directory**

```
  let rootDir = process.cwd()
  console.log("Current Directory"+ rootDir)

  let outDir = './out/';
  console.log("Out Directory"+ outDir)

  if (!fs.existsSync(outDir)){
      fs.mkdirSync(outDir);
  }else{
      console.log("Directory already exist");
  }
   
  // Save the raw file for each asset to the current working directory
  saveArrayAsFile(arrayBuffer,  outDir+ "fileName"+ new Date().getTime()+".png")
```

**Save file function**

```
const saveArrayAsFile =  (arrayBuffer, filePath)=> {
      fs.writeFile(filePath, Buffer.from(arrayBuffer), 'binary',  (err)=> {
          if (err) {
              console.log("There was an error writing the image")
          }
          else {
              console.log("Written File :" + filePath)
          }
      });
};
```