# puppeteer page.evaluate -- get progress

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have the following code to attempt to get an array buffer from the current page in puppeteer:

```
await page.evaluate(cb => {

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = location.href;
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log((x.response));
    }
    x.responseType="arraybuffer";
    x.open("GET",url,true);
    x.send("");
});
```

Currently I'm trying to catch the console.log to get the response:

```
page.on("console", c => {
    console.log("Consoling", c._args[0]._remoteObject); //thought this would get the arraybuffer
});
```

although it's not giving me the actual arraybuffer object, just this (if I just do c):

```
Consoling [ JSHandle {
    _context:
     ExecutionContext { _client: [CDPSession], _world: [DOMWorld], _contextId: 3 },
    _client:
     CDPSession {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 27,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _callbacks: Map {},
       _connection: [Connection],
       _targetType: 'page',
       _sessionId: '817AEFBC94D1B52BC15559269CB67A61' },
    _remoteObject:
     { type: 'object',
       subtype: 'arraybuffer',
       className: 'ArrayBuffer',
       description: 'ArrayBuffer(40285)',
       objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":1}',
       preview: [Object] },
    _disposed: false } ]
```

and the following for the current console.log (c[0]._remoteObject):

```
Consoling { type: 'object',
  subtype: 'arraybuffer',
  className: 'ArrayBuffer',
  description: 'ArrayBuffer(40285)',
  objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":1}',
  preview:
   { type: 'object',
     subtype: 'arraybuffer',
     description: 'ArrayBuffer(40285)',
     overflow: false,
     properties: [] } }
```

It's giving me some nice descriptions of the arrabuffer liek I might see in a console (before extending the object), but I guess its running a JSON.stringify on the entire thing so I'm guessing the arraybuffer data is lost?

***Is there any [other] way to get data from page.evaluate during the page progress and not just at the end of the resolve? How can I get an arraybuffer object generated on the page? Do I have to simply send it through another XMLHTTPRequest or websocket back to the server?***

Answer (score 0):

## Typed array

Excerpt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41329907/6161265) by rsp:

> There are no ArrayBuffers in the JSON format (only strings, numbers, booleans, null, objects and arrays) so if you want to save an ArrayBuffer in JSON then you'll have to represent it in one of those types (probably a string or an array of numbers).
>
> Then when you read the JSON you will have to convert it back into an ArrayBuffer, reversing the transformation that you did before.

In puppeteer, everything is serialized so the context is lost. You cannot share the same reference in node and browser.

So, we can convert the typed array to string (or base64 string), then pass that, whenever we get the value, we can simply convert it back.

This will convert your string to Uint8Array as you can see. However to convert to other types, unfortunately you will have to code that yourself since only you know the structure of the response.

```
const stringToArray = (str) => new Uint8Array([...str].map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
```

So you can log like this,

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    var typedArrayExample = new Uint8Array(2);
    typedArrayExample[0] = 15;
    typedArrayExample[1] = 20;
    // typedArrayExample should be Uint8Array(2) [15, 20]
    // typeof typedArrayExample === "object"
    // typedArrayExample.constructor === Uint8Array

    if (typedArrayExample.constructor === Uint8Array) {
      console.log(String.fromCharCode(...typedArrayExample))
    }
})
```

The page.on('console') event,

```
page.on("console", c => {
    console.log(c.args())
    const {
      value
    } = c._args[0]._remoteObject;
    // convert the string back
    console.log("Consoling", stringToArray(value));
});
```

Now running this will result in,

```
Consoling Uint8Array [ 15, 20 ]
```

## Websocket/Ajax request

You can create a websocket server using `ws` package,

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: 8081
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: ', new Uint8Array(message));
  });
});
```

And then send binary data from page to that websocket,

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

    ws.onopen = function open() {
      const array = new Uint8Array(2);
      array[0] = 15;
      array[1] = 20;

      ws.send(array);
    }
})
```

Result:

```
received:  Uint8Array [ 15, 20 ]
```

Make sure to close the connections afterwards. You can also take advantage of multiple chrome tabs/pages to avoid cors related problems. :)

You will recieve a buffer, you can convert it to